# It works with int but not with double

Tags: java, double

The following program works as it should work (it takes words from a stream and sets the longest and the shortest String.length value (max and min))

```
String s;
int max = 0;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int words = 0;
int totallength = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNext()) {
    s = in.next();
    words++;
    int length = s.length();
    totallength += length;
    if(length > max) {
        max = length;
    }

    if(length < min) {
        min = length;
    }
}

System.out.println("max: " + max);
System.out.println("med: " + totallength/words);
System.out.println("min: " + min);
```

but the function med (average length of the words) returns a result only if it's of int type (which is partially useless).
If I set it as double with:

```
double med = (double)totallength/(double)words;
System.out.println("max: " + max);
System.out.println("med: " + med);
System.out.println("min: " + min);
```

it only prints the "max value" and the program stops. Why is that happening?

P.S. the stream is inserted in console and it ends with the shortcut Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D depending on the OS

Some examples:

```
1
22
333
4444
max: 4

hello
helloo    hello
max: 6

the program does

does not work
for some reason
max: 7
```

Comment: I've corrected a typo in your code which prevented it from compiling. Please reverse it if I was incorrect to do so.

Comment: Thank you I noticed it, if there are typo errors is because I quickly translated it from another language

Comment: No crash, it just prints the max value but not the other two prints. And if I remove the "med printing" while using the double it doesn't stop and prints the minimum
so it's an error in the usage of the double but I can't understand

Comment: Seems to print the `med` for me (albeit `int` and `double` predictably give different results with division) -> https://ideone.com/20uFti

Comment: You've not posted your [mcve] using doubles -- the actual program that fails. Until you do this, I fear that we'll have no answer.

Comment: it fails every program
but I'm gonna post few examples

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not using an IDE, I'm using the console, and the error keeps happening even after restaring it a few times

Comment: @dulindraxe: who said anything about IDE? I'm saying that you need to show the full exact program without typos that causes the problem. You've shown one program that works, and code fragments that you state don't work. Show the full thing.

Comment: Ah that was @Carcigenicate, not me

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm messing up a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Scanner` reading to this:

```java
while(true) {
  s = in.nextLine();
  if(s.isEmpty())
    break;
```

I think the problem is that you are actually interrupting your program when you want to end the input stream, and the behaviour becomes unpredictable after that. As you can see for some people your program works fine, but for you (and for me too) it doesn't. If you change it to my version, scanner reading is gonna end after empty line.

Comment: It works!
Thank you, do you know what can cause this behaviour? Is there something I can do other than interrupting the program like that?

Comment: It's because you are stopping a program when you try to interrupt the scanner reading (Ctrl+C sends a break signal to program). When you stop a program you have no control when it's actually gonna stop - it can execute few lines more, stop immediately, or simply finish everything and then stop. This change simply breaks out of the while loop to stop reading user input when the user enters empty line (`s.isEmpty()`), you could make user write 'end' or 'stop' and then do `if(s.equals("stop"))` or something like that.